# Explicit termination method 'close'

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using `volley` and after a couple of hits below exception is thrown.
The application is crashing showing following error.

> E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>                                                                      java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
>                                                                          at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:103)
>                                                                          at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:464)
>                                                                          at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:530)
>                                                                          at java.net.Socket.setSoSndTimeout(Socket.java:1194)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.Connection.setTimeouts(Connection.java:508)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:400)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:356)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:273)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:422)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:99)
>                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
>                                                                          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
>                                                                          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)

Below is the code snippet

```
public void processServiceResponseEntity(final String serviceName, final String serviceRequest,
            final int method, final String key, final Map<String, String> queryParams, final Map<String, String> header,
            final Map<String, String> pathVariables)
            throws YaggerCustomException
    {

        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        final User user = databaseHandler.getUserDetails();
        String url = serviceName;

        Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(method,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String res) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + res);
                        if (currentObject != null) {
                            currentObject.postYaggerServiceCall(res, key);
                        }
                        // setResponse(res);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        showSnackbar(serviceName, serviceRequest, method, key, queryParams, header, pathVariables);
                        currentObject.postYaggerServiceCall(null, key);
                        setError(error.getMessage());
                       // ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(new YaggerCustomException(error.getMessage()));
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType()
            {
                if (getContentType() == null)
                {
                    return "application/json";
                }
                else
                {
                    return getContentType();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                byte[] byt = null;
                this.getParams();
                if (serviceRequest != null)
                    byt = serviceRequest.getBytes();
                return byt;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
                    throws AuthFailureError
            {
                Map<String, String> oauthHeader = new HashMap<>();
                oauthHeader.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                if(user != null)
                    oauthHeader.put("Authorization", user.getTokenType() + " " + user.getToken());
                if (header != null && !header.isEmpty()) {
                    oauthHeader.putAll(header);
                }
                oauthHeader.putAll(super.getHeaders());
                return oauthHeader;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams()
                    throws AuthFailureError
            {
                if (queryParams == null)
                    return Collections.<String, String>emptyMap();
                return queryParams;
            }

            @Override
            public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy()
            {
                return new DefaultRetryPolicy(AppConfig.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, AppConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        AppConfig.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(AppConfig.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, AppConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                AppConfig.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, key == null ? serviceName : key);


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code, especially code that deals with closable resources.

Comment: Edited. Please check

Comment: This stacktrace suggest you have opened a ressource without closing it after. `Closable` objects, have a `close` method that you must call.

Comment: How do i find it out ?